# Strange Values in SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS table RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Strange Values in SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS table RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID column

I’ve been trying to understand some strange values in the RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID column of SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS when RESOURCE_TYPE is “OBJECT”. Although these should be object Ids, I cannot determine what object they actually refer to.

I’ve tried everything I can think of, including querying all system tables with columns of type INT and BIGINT to see if I can find the value. No luck. The funny values actually appear in SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS, SYS.SYSLOCKINFO and SP_LOCK.

(Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit), version 9.00.4053.00 (SP3 + a security patch))